# How to find your own questions?

Tags: support, search

I'm looking for how to find your own questions.

Comment: Click on the reputation icon,there you 'll find your question

Answer (score 12):

There's a [tab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/239481/french-albator?tab=questions) for it on your profile. You can also click the search box at the top-right and search for [`user:me is:question`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion).